# What is difference between Command$ and Command in VB 6?

Tags: vb6, arguments, type-declaration

What is difference between Command$ and Command in VB 6?

```
MsgBox Command$
MsgBox Command
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Any time you see a `$` after a function in VB 6, it means that the function is a `String` version**, meaning it returns a value of type `String`. The version without the dollar sign is a `Variant` function, which of course means it returns a value of type `Variant`.

In general, you should *always* prefer the `String` versions over the `Variant` versions.

The dollar sign also means the same thing if it appears after a variable name in lieu of a specified type. Here, it's part of a larger family of shorthand "type declaration characters" that were necessary in earlier versions of BASIC, but firmly antiquated by the time even VB 6 arrived on the scene. For example:

```
Dim name$
```

indicates a variable named `name` that is of type `String`. The alternative (and preferred!) notation is:

```
Dim name As String
```

In case you're dealing with legacy code where these appear, here's the entire list for completeness:

```
&   Long
%   Integer
#   Double
!   Single
@   Decimal
$   String
```

Answer (score 5):

They both return the same string but Command returns the string in a Variant.

There are actually quite a few VB functions that do this. The $ at the end indicates the function returns a string while the counterparts return variants.