# Enum in VB.NET - End of Statement is Expected

Tags: vb.net, enums

These lines of code of mine produced same error

```
   Enum ConnectionState
       INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = 0x1
       INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = 0x2
       INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = 0x4
       INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED = 0x10
       INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE = 0x20
       INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = 0x40
    End Enum
```

It says:

> End of statement expected

I tried to do Google search and it appears that I follow a correct format. For example these lines below are valid.

```
Public Enum InterfaceColors
    MistyRose = &HE1E4FF&
    SlateGray = &H908070&
    DodgerBlue = &HFF901E&
    DeepSkyBlue = &HFFBF00&
    SpringGreen = &H7FFF00&
    ForestGreen = &H228B22&
    Goldenrod = &H20A5DA&
    Firebrick = &H2222B2&
End Enum
```

These are working too

```
Enum SecurityLevel
    IllegalEntry = -1
    MinimumSecurity = 0
    MaximumSecurity = 1
End Enum
```

Both were taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Can someone advise me what was wrong with my lines?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB doesn't understand `0x` notation.  VB uses `&H` instead.

```
Enum ConnectionState 
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = &H1 
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = &H2 
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = &H4 
    INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED = &H10 
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE = &H20 
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = &H40 
End Enum
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone advise me what was wrong with my lines?

You've not declared the hexadecimal literals correctly.

You've written them the way you would in C# (with a `0x` prefix), but VB.NET expects them to be written with a `&H` prefix, just like your sample code shows.

Indeed, the error message could probably be more helpful, but what it's trying to tell you is that it doesn't recognize the `0x` sequence and instead expected to find the end of the line of code.

Change your enum to look like this:

```
Enum ConnectionState
   INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = &H1
   INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = &H2
   INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = &H4
   INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED = &H10
   INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE = &H20
   INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = &H40
End Enum
```

The sample code shown in the question also suffixes each of the literals with the `&` character. That's [a holdover from the days of BASIC gone by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4527103/366904); it tells the compiler that the literal represents a `Long` type. You probably pulled that sample enum declaration from some old VB 6 code, but there's little risk of your values overflowing given the expanded range of the `Integer` type in VB.NET.

Comment: Wasn't the `&` appended to variablenames to declare them as Long? Or appended an `L` to the value to tell the compiler that the value should be treated as a Long? Ref: [Type Characters (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @Nicholas: Yes. But what I said is still accurate; from the article you linked: *"Literals can also use the identifier type characters (%, &, @, !, #, $)"* For whatever reason, when declaring enumerated constants, particularly those from the Win32 API, the `&` suffix was ubiquitous to indicate that a literal value should be interpreted as a `Long`.