# What is 'Command' of VB6 into VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, migration, vb6-migration

I am migrating an application from VB6 to VB.Net, Which is using the **Command** Expression.

My question is: Which is the "equivalent" of VB6 **Command** in following Code?
$ is returning String in VB6. So I can Remove it... But even after removing **$**, Command will give me error that **Command is an interface type and cannot be used as Expression.**

[image]

I would try to write **'New Command().CommandText'** in replace of **Command**. is it right way to write?

Comment: This is two questions, which means that you haven't really thought about the problem sufficiently. The first question is, what does `Command$` do in VB6. Do you know? If not, have you searched online to find out? If not, why not? Once you know what the actual functionality is that you're trying to reproduce, then you can simply search for the best way to do that in VB.NET. You need to have done all you can for yourself before posting here and I don't think that you have. I think that you have simply copied some code and immediately asked for help when it didn't work. That's not good enough.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think you are overstating it. We expect people to show some effort, which the OP has done. The question is at least a good starting point and like all of them can be improved if needed. A lot of VB6 questions come from people who not surprisingly may not have a lot of VB6 experience - ie some old app has been dumped on them to maintain. If they are also a junior programmer than it can be hard to know what the right questions even are.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Visual_Basic_6_to_.NET_Function_Equivalents

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, I think you are overstating it. *"We expect people to show some effort, which the OP has done"*. They've copied and pasted some code. Where's the effort in that? I have no experience with VB6 at all but I do have experience with search engines, so I know that, if I wanted to know what X did in VB6, I'd type "vb6 x" into a search engine. That would be some effort, but there's no sign of even that here. Being new to programming or a programming language doesn't mean that you're new to software, the internet or logic in general.

Comment: `command()` the same as in VB6. In VB a `$` suffix means the function returns a string rather than a variant and there is no practicable difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between Command$ and Command in VB 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527055/what-is-difference-between-command-and-command-in-vb-6)

Comment: Do you understand what a Namespace collision is?  Because that is what is causing your issue.  Add `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` (yes I know its is typically a global import, but do it regardless) to the code file's Imports section before the `Imports ADODB` and watch the error message change.  Hint: you want the `Command` function from that added import.

Comment: @TnTinMn, it is working. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of VB6's `Command$` function in VB.NET is `Environment.CommandLine`

Please refer to the code sample below:

```
Class Example
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Console.WriteLine()
      '  Invoke this sample with an arbitrary set of command line arguments.
      Console.WriteLine("CommandLine: {0}", Environment.CommandLine)
   End Sub 
End Class 
' The example displays output like the following:
'       C:\>CommandLine ARBITRARY TEXT
'       
'       CommandLine: CommandLine ARBITRARY TEXT
```

If you want to get an array of the command line arguments you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`